# Cómo añadir la codificación (e.g. "UTF-8") a un InputStreamReader

Tags: java, utf-8, codificación

Quisiera saber si a este código en concreto se le puede añadir codificación UTF-8.

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       try {

     URL url = new URL("http://dukegames.tk/archivos/changelog.txt");
    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    uc.connect();
    //Creamos el objeto con el que vamos a leer
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    String contenido = "";
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        contenido += inputLine + "\n";
    }
    txt.setText(contenido);
    in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

... Lo que hace este código es mostrarme un archivo de texto remoto en un JEditorPane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente sí es posible añadir la codificación. La clase [`java.io.InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) tiene varios constructores, uno de ellos, aparte de recibir el flujo de bytes ([`java.io.InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)), también recibe la codificación. Es decir:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
);
```

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1")
);
```

Adicionalmente, desde Java 7 puedes utilizar las constantes definidas en la clase [`java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
);
```

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
);
```

<sub>NOTA: Parece ser que el archivo que intentas leer está codificado en ISO-8859-1.</sub>

Comment: Correcto, con la codificación ISO-8859-1 he podido leer las ñ y tildes sin ningún problema, no me había fijado en ese detalle del archivo, muchísimas gracias me ha servido!

Comment: hola yo estoy intentando leer este archivo https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2000/pg2000.txt y no he podido quizás fueras tan amable de ayudarme por favor